# Visual Studio UI lag in Macos VMware

Tags: flutter, macos, virtual-machine, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run Visual Studio on Macos VMware, but after booting, the following picture appears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwk3h.png)

For your information: the specifications of my device are somewhat high, and I downloaded Android and it worked normally